# What problem does the entity reference module solve?

Tags: entities

From the [relevant documentation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) in drupal.org:

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities

That doesn't help understand the purpose of this feature and what problem it was created to solve.

We can already associate two entity types (say, content type and taxonomy type) by creating a node which contains both a text field and a taxonomy (type) term/s field, so, how's an "entity reference" association is different and for what common purpose?

I prefer to ask a Drupal developer here instead of reaching my own conclusion about this as a Drupal site builder.

Comment: You can look at the [Drupal 7 docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/entity-reference/getting-started) for this: "... build relationships between entities in Drupal"

Comment: @berliner what is the nature of that relationship and what problem does it solve, that's what I'm trying to understand... For example, when I create a view that contains both node data and taxonomy data, there there is a relationship ! So what is different with entity reference?

Comment: The problem it solves is "references in your data model". You can relate objects to each other, enabling you to work with those relations in all kind of different ways. You can for example also create a parent child relationship for node content (think hierarchical content structure), or reference a set of related nodes per node by using a multi-value entity reference field on your content type. Question back to you: How would you go about solving references between your different entity types? Try to research that and the solution you will come up with is entity references.

Comment: @berliner I didn't understand anything you wrote but I should try to read the answer below and try to figure a clue about this Drupal term from there...

Comment: @berliner in case you downvoted, I didn't mean any offense when I said I didn't understand anything you wrote. I should have also phrased "sorry but I didn't understand generally anything you wrote".

Comment: Relating a node to a term is an entity reference. What's the disconnect? Pointing any entity at another one is literally "entity reference"ing.

Comment: @Kevin okay so if entity references are done with the core itself why do we need an external module named "Entity reference"? Perhaps the **naming of the module** was just bad? If so, what should have been a more meaningful name?

Comment: Entity reference is provided by core and has been since version 8. There is no module needed for this unless you are on 7, which is this module. What's in core is an evolution of this module.

Comment: @Kevin my issue is understanding what is the particular action that the module allows us to do if other types of "entity-references" already done and were done in Drupal 7 or lesser without installing the module?

Comment: In Drupal 6 and 7, if I remember correctly one *could* reference entities (say, a taxonomy term field in a content type) without installing this module.

Comment: The explanation is on the module page, I am not sure what else to say. Taxonomy Terms are not the only kind of entities in Drupal. An entity reference field lets you reference any entity, not just a specific one (Taxonomy Term). I don't understand why we are talking about Drupal 6 or 7 when the question is tagged 9? This module only exists for Drupal 7. People were creating fields that could only reference SPECIFIC entities, a generic entity reference allows anything. Thats the difference. https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/organizing-content-with-taxonomies/about-taxonomies#s-taxonomy-principles

Comment: I removed the _9_ tag because it's confusing in this context - as others have mentioned the module you're talking about only exists for Drupal 7. Please feel free to add it back in if it's relevant, but please make it clear in the question body what that relevance is if you do

Comment: Incidentally, the naming of the module was perfect (IMO) as it 100% encapsulates the module's purpose in just two words. It's so perfect that the functionality kept that name when it was moved into core for Drupal 8. Kevin hit the nail on the head with his last comment: this module is for referencing entities for which a reference field type doesn't already exist, or even for people who want to standardise their entity reference fields in Drupal 7, and stop using the term reference field type etc altogether.

Comment: The difference is that the module is able to handle references to any entity, instead of having more modules to handle specific references. That module is now part of Drupal 8, where even the node author field is an entity reference.

Comment: @Kevin I wanted to focus the discussion in relation to how "entity reference" is implemented in Drupal 9 hence the tag, but it was a mistake it's good it was removed.

Comment: @Clive thank you, about `this module is for referencing entities for which a reference field type doesn't already exist` well, I think a better name would be *"entity reference anything"* and clearly stating in the module page "not only entities which you can reference/exchange content from by the core".

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of site building, consider the following.

Say you allow all authenticated users to post articles, and you want to let the users categorize the articles.

To do this, you could take one of two approaches. (Of course there are more options, but we will pick two here to keep it simple.)

- Add a field of type **List (text)** to the article content type and enter all the categories in the field settings.
- Add a field of type **entity reference (taxonomy)** and set the reference to a "tags" taxonomy.

With the text list approach, you have a fixed set of categories.  If you want to expand the list of categories, you can edit the list-- but users can't add their own categories unless they have permission to edit the field settings.  In the real world, you would never give users such permission because then a malicious user could mess up the site by deleting all the categories or adding some profanity, etc.

However, with the entity reference approach, users can now create a category by adding a new taxonomy term-- all they need is permission to add terms to the "tags" category.

This is the advantage of entity reference-- you can make sets of entities to create useful structures, which you can then manipulate in modules like Views.  What is important here is that entity reference allows you to separate concerns-- for example, you can make articles as node entities, and tags as taxonomy term entities-- instead of trying to smash everything together in one giant entity.

You can create specialized entities to accurately model each kind of data you have, and then link those together logically with entity references.  This is much more maintainable over the long term than putting everything on a single entity type, which is what you would have to do if you didn't have a module like Entity Reference.

Comment: What is the difference between letting a user edit the list to letting the user edit a taxonomy type? I mean, in both cases that user could CRUD and add profanity, etc.

Comment: With a list, all the permissions are tied to editing fields for the content type-- you do not have CRUD permissions.  With a taxonomy type, you have separate CRUD permissions for the taxonomy, which is why this is almost always implemented with entity references to taxonomy.

Comment: @GeorgeLucas See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model for a conceptual overview of what's happening here. The module you linked to in the original post is simply the D7-specific UI which allows you to create those relationships

Answer (score 1):

Drupal Commerce provides a good example of why entity references are necessary.

In Drupal Commerce, you have entities for lots of things, like

- Stores (you can have multiple stores or a single store)
- Products
- Orders
- Payment methods

All of these are separate entity types because a store and a product represent different things.

In Drupal, a good basic strategy is to create a different "entity" type for each "thing" you want to represent.

However, if you do that, you quickly notice there is a problem-- you have lots of "things", but how are they linked?  The link is often an entity reference.

For example, when you make a order, the order should contain a reference to the products that were ordered.  You also need to know what payment method was used, and which store the order was made from.  Entity references are what enables you to do this.

Comment: There must be some background data I lack, or something crucial that I miss here or that the examples aren't both down to earth and simple enough . After building websites with Drupal since about year 2010, I don't get this one idea and still after the comment and answers, but I don't give up in trying to understand it !